# Show a row for every result between 3 mySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that can have multiple records linking to another table, but I don't want mySQL to combine rows together. Example:

- **test_main** contains fields mainID, field1.
- **test_veg** contains a record with a name of a vegetable, linked to the record in test_main with ID=1
- **test_fruit** contains two records each with a name of a fruit, both linked to the record in test_main with ID=1

In this example there are three records that link to test_main – one test_veg and two test_fruit. I want to get those 3 rows to give a result like:

```
field1               vegName  fruitName
-------------------  -------  ---------
stuff in main table  cabbage  NULL
stuff in main table  NULL     apple
stuff in main table  NULL     pear
```

I would also like records from test_main that don't have any test_veg or test_fruit records linked to them.

This seems so simple but I can’t get it to work. Any ideas?

If I only had two tables (e.g. test_main and test_veg), a left join would work. With 3 tables, two left joins return only two rows:

```
SELECT  test_main.field1, test_veg.vegName, test_fruit.fruitName
FROM test_main
LEFT  JOIN test_veg ON test_veg.mainID = test_main.mainID
LEFT  JOIN test_fruit ON test_fruit.mainID = test_main.mainID
WHERE test_main.mainID=1

field1               vegName  fruitName
-------------------  -------  ---------
stuff in main table  cabbage  apple
stuff in main table  cabbage  pear
```

NB I’m stuck with mySQL3, which means no fancy things like SELECTs within WHEREs, nor UNIONs.

Comment: could you show the datas please?

Comment: mySQL3 means MySQL version 3?

Comment: Yes, version 3 of mySQL :-(    @sgeddes' Fiddle below shows exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very cool article I read a while back about tricking MySQL3.x into mimicking a `UNION`.  You need to create a DUMMY table with as many rows as needed for the Unions.  So if you have 1 union (which is 2 different select statements), you'd need 2 rows in the dummy table.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT m.field1, v.vegName, f.fruitName
FROM test_main m
INNER JOIN dummy d 
  ON d.id < 3
LEFT JOIN test_veg v 
  ON v.mainID = m.mainID 
  and d.id = 1
LEFT JOIN test_fruit f 
  ON f.mainID = m.mainID 
  and d.id = 2
WHERE m.mainid=1
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28c31/8) to better help you follow along.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the result I need!

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`is also useful to avoid multiple rows of test_main with missing test_veg and test_fruit.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you can add the following to the `where` clause:

```
test_veg.mainID is NULL and test_fruit.main_id is NULL
```

This will get main things that are neither fruits nor vegetables.

However, I think you have a problem with your data.

Everything on the same output row has the same MaindID.  So, cabbage needs to have the same `mainID` as apple and pear.  However, if I understand the question correctly, then mainId is supposed to be distinguishing between things like apples and pears.

Comment: the mainID is supposed to allow fruit or veg records (so in the example, apples, pears, cabbage) to be linked to the test_main table. sgeddes shows what I mean, but thanks for contributing.

Comment: @user535673 . . . The ids are repeated in the table, so the same id can be used for a vegetable and for a fruit?  Bad database design.

Comment: No, the IDs are foreign keys for the test_main table. The example didn't have IDs for the vegetable or fruit tables because they weren't really relevant to the question. Sorry for the confusion – yes, it would be bad if both used the same ID.

Comment: @user535673 . . . As I explain, in the data example you have in the question, apples, pears, and cabbage would all have to have the same MainId in order for the rows to contain both a fruit and a vegetable.